# Which HTML element for to set maximum length of line and max and maximum number of lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

i need input, where i can set maximum length of line and maximum number of lines. Which element should I use? Or maybe should i write this in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To create a multi-line text input, use the HTML  tag. You can set the size of a text area using the cols and rows attributes.

try to use this custom validator for limit its maximum chars in each row.

```
<textarea siInput [(ngModel)]="myTextarea" style="resize:none;  white-space: both;" rows="20" (keyup)="onKeyAction()"(keydown)="onKeyAction()" id="textID" maxlength="{{maxTextAreaLength}}"></textarea>


myTextarea;
maxTextLineLength = 10;

onKeyAction() {
if (this.myTextarea) {
  var lines = this.myTextarea.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length >= this.maxTextLineLength) {
      lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, this.maxTextLineLength);
    }
  }
  this.myTextarea = lines.join('');
 }
}
```

Created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wkycj) for help.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp) there is an attribute `maxlength` for textarea.

Comment: maxlength sets max number of characters per textarea, not per line

Comment: glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use some function like for-loop and recursion might be useful in your case and just to be more helpful can you provide more details about your project